# DB2 join with case when and nearest timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to figure out the best way, in DB2, to use a join and a 'case when' based on the nearest timestamp of another table. I have a main query for activity of events:

```
SELECT eventActivity, eventUser, eventTimestamp
            FROM eventActivities
            WHERE id = 123;
```

And a 2nd query with related status codes

```
SELECT * from eventStatus where event_id = 123;
```

The first query returns

```
eventActivity   |   eventUser   |   eventTimestamp
----------------------------------------------------------------
Status Change       John            2019-09-17 00:00:07.541854
Status Change       John            2019-09-17 00:00:09.235154
Event Closed        John            2019-09-17 00:00:10.000000
```

The 2nd returns

```
event_id   |   event_status   |   timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------
123             Progress            2019-09-17 00:00:07.541921
123             Cancelled           2019-09-17 00:00:09.340911
```

What I'd like to do is make it so that I can join with the first query  and only if the activity is 'Status Change' get the event_status that has the nearest timestamp, if that makes sense.

So my desired output for the above would be something like this:

```
SELECT eventActivity, eventUser, eventTimestamp, case when eventActivity = 'Status Change' select event_status from eventStatus where event_id = 123 with nearest timestamp
FROM eventActivities
WHERE id = 123;

eventActivity   |   eventUser   |   event_timestamp            |   event_status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status Change       John            2019-09-17 00:00:07.541854    Progress
Status Change       John            2019-09-17 00:00:09.235154    Cancelled
Event Closed        John            2019-09-17 00:00:10.000000    null
```

Is there a way I can pretty feasibly do this in db2?

Comment: Does the `eventActivities` table have an actual primary key?

Comment: If you want to get the closest event why is the event_status NULL for the last row? This would lead to the point that you are looking for the last one before that timestamp ...

Comment: because there isn't a status for that one, but yes it would have a status as well, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ea.eventActivity, ea.eventUser, ea.eventTimestamp,
       (SELECT es.status
        FROM eventstatus es
        WHERE es.event_id = ea.id AND
              ea.eventActivity = 'Status Change' AND
              es.timestamp <= ea.eventtimestamp
        ORDER BY es.timestamp DESC
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
       ) as status
FROM eventActivities ea
WHERE ea.id = 123;
```

Comment: Tweaked this a bit and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.eventActivity, a.eventUser, a.eventTimestamp, s.event_status
FROM eventActivities a
LEFT JOIN TABLE
(
SELECT s.event_status
FROM eventStatus s
WHERE s.event_id = a.id
ORDER BY abs(timestampdiff(1, char(a.eventTimestamp - s.timestamp)))
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) s ON a.eventActivity = 'Status Change'
WHERE a.id = 123
;
```

The closest `eventStatus.timestamp` value may be more or less than `eventActivities.eventTimestamp`. It doesn't matter for the select statement above.